# Time-based scaling with Kubernetes CronJob: How to avoid deployments overriding minReplicas

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob, hpa

I have a HorizontalPodAutoscalar to scale my pods based on CPU. The minReplicas here is set to `5`:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: myapp-web
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: myapp-web
  minReplicas: 5 
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 50
```

I've then added Cron jobs to scale up/down my horizontal pod autoscaler based on time of day:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: production
  name: cron-runner
rules:
- apiGroups: ["autoscaling"]
  resources: ["horizontalpodautoscalers"]
  verbs: ["patch", "get"]

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: cron-runner
  namespace: production
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-cron-runner
  namespace: production
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: cron-runner
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-cron-runner
  namespace: production
---

apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: django-scale-up-job
  namespace: production
spec:
  schedule: "56 11 * * 1-6"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0 # Remove after successful completion
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1 # Retain failed so that we see it
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: sa-cron-runner
          containers:
          - name: django-scale-up-job
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - kubectl patch hpa myapp-web --patch '{"spec":{"minReplicas":8}}'
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
----
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: django-scale-down-job
  namespace: production
spec:
  schedule: "30 20 * * 1-6"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0 # Remove after successful completion
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1 # Retain failed so that we see it
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: sa-cron-runner
          containers:
          - name: django-scale-down-job
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - kubectl patch hpa myapp-web --patch '{"spec":{"minReplicas":5}}'
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

This works really well, except that now when I deploy it overwrites this `minReplicas` value with the minReplicas in the HorizontalPodAutoscaler spec (in my case, this is set to 5)

I'm deploying my HPA using `kubectl apply -f ~/autoscale.yaml`

Is there a way of handling this situation? Do I need to create some kind of shared logic so that my deployment scripts can work out what the minReplicas value should be? Or is there a simpler way of handling this?

Comment: Hello, I'm having a difficulty to understand your question. Could you tell the whole scenario for the time based `HPA` scaling of yours? What exactly you mean by overwriting the `minReplicas` (as it should looking at your example)? You should create `HPA` that would be encompassing both situation (high load/low load) in a single `HPA` basing on the available metrics.

Comment: Ah sorry - I've added the HPA config which should hopefully make it clearer

Comment: If you would like to avoid overwriting the value of `replicas` in your `Deployment` (each new `create`/`apply`) you could try to update your `Deployment` with [JSON merge patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-json-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Ah...you mean each deployment you use a merge patch instead of apply, then this will only update values that have explicitly changed? Will give that a go and revert back if so, sounds smart.

Comment: I've had a go with this and clarified the problem. Looks like it's definitely the HPA `minReplicas` value that's overwriting the one set by the CronJob (as opposed to the `replicas` in the Deployment). I tried using JSON merge to deploy the HPA (`kubectl patch -f autoscale.yaml --type=merge  -p "$(cat autoscale.yaml)"`) and it didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hello, I think we've had a bit of misunderstanding. I thought you are not changing the `HPA` resource but only the `tag`/`version` of the container during the upgrade process (in the `Deployment`). That's why I suggested going with the `JSON` merge patch for it, where you just add the changes to it and not whole resource. Please take a look on the answer I've posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could also consider the following two options:

---

#### Use helm to manage the life-cycle of your application with lookup function:

The main idea behind this solution is to query the state of specific cluster resource (here `HPA`) before trying to create/recreate it with `helm` `install`/`upgrade` commands.

- *[Helm.sh: Docs: Chart template guide: Functions and pipelines: Using the lookup function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function)*

I mean to check the current `minReplicas` value each time before you upgrade your application stack.

---

#### Manage the `HPA` resource separately to application manifest files

Here you can handover this task to a dedicated `HPA` operator, which can coexist with your `CronJobs` that adjust `minReplicas` according specific schedule:

- *[Banzaicloud.com: Blog: K8S HPA Operator](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-hpa-operator/)*

Comment: Great answer. I haven't had chance to try the approaches yet, but will accept for now. Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

How to scale down CroneJob not deleting. is there any command like this?

`kubectl scale cronjob tms-cron --replicas=0 -n develop`

My cronjob yaml is here

```
--
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: tms-cron
  namespace: develop
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: s-jenkins
          containers:
            - name: tms-cronjob
              image: docker-c2.example.com/netcore/netcore-v:v0.BUILDVERSION
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              envFrom:
                - secretRef:
                    name: netcore-secrets
                - configMapRef:
                    name: netcore-configmap
              command:
                - php
              args:
                - artisan
                - schedule:run
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```